# ¿Cómo realizar un seguimiento de las vistas de páginas PDF en GA 4?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, google-analytics, events

Administro una revista de historia que publica sus artículos en PDF. Estos archivos PDF están alojados en el propio hosting de la web y hago un seguimiento de sus visitas en Google Analytics añadiendo a sus enlaces el siguiente evento:

```
onclick="ga('send','pageview','/file_name.pdf');"
```

En Google Analytics 4 esto no funciona. ¿Alguien sabe cómo realizar un seguimiento de las vistas de páginas PDF en GA4?

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Arts, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar, como y donde estas incluyendo el script de `gtag`?

Comment: En GA 4 todo es más simple. No tienes que poner esto en el onclick: `"ga('send','pageview','/file_name.pdf');"` sino activar la descarga de archivos en la configuración de Google Analytics, [ver la doc para más detalles](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13136367?hl=en). Esto registrará datos de todas las descargas de archivo. Si quieres monitorear la descarga sólo de archivos específicos, puedes usar Google Tag Manager, revisa [este post](https://measureschool.com/track-pdf-downloads-in-google-analytics-4/) donde se explica las ventajas / desventajas de los distintos enfoques.